# Why am i receiving null when state is passed through Link in react?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Here is the code
This is the parent component from where the Link tag is defined and the state is passed
**Parent Component**

```
import React from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import "../HomePage/TopPicks.css";


const TopCards = ({item,id,handleCartClick}) => {
  const {title,image,price,desc,rating} = item

  const toIndian = (number)=>{
    let x=number.toString();
    let lastThree = x.substring(x.length-3);
    let otherNumbers = x.substring(0,x.length-3);
    if(otherNumbers != '')
        lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
    let res = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;

    return res;
  }

  const myData = {
    item: item,
    handleCartClick: handleCartClick,
  };
  return (
    
    <div className="col-sm-3 mb-3 mb-sm-0 topPicks_cards ">
      <Link to= 'product-details' state={myData}>
      <div className="card topPicks_card" style={{width: "286px"}}>
      <img src= {image} className="card-img-top" alt="..." />
      <div className="card-body">
        <h6 className="card-title">{title}</h6>
        <p className="card-text">{`Rs. ${toIndian(price*80)}`}</p>
        <div className="rating">
        {rating.rate}
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </Link>
    </div>


    
  )
}

export default TopCards
```

This is the child component where the state is received
**Child component**

```
import React,{useState} from 'react'
import { useLocation } from 'react-router-dom'
import Navbar from '../HomePage/Navbar'
import '../ProductDetails/productDetails.css'
import Footer from "../HomePage/Footer"


const ProductDetails = () => {

  const location = useLocation()
  console.log(location);
  const {state} = location
  // console.log(state);
  
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  //This will handle the decrement of the no of product
  const handleDecrement = ()=>{
    setCount(preValue =>{
      if (preValue < 1) {
        return 0;
      }
      return preValue = preValue-1;
    })
    
  }
  //This will handle the increment of the no of product

  const handleIncrement = ()=>{
    setCount(preValue => {
      return preValue = preValue+1;
    })
  }
  // Putting the commas in Rs
  const toIndian = (number)=>{
    let x=number.toString();
    let lastThree = x.substring(x.length-3);
    let otherNumbers = x.substring(0,x.length-3);
    if(otherNumbers !== '')
        lastThree = ',' + lastThree;
    let res = otherNumbers.replace(/\B(?=(\d{2})+(?!\d))/g, ",") + lastThree;
    return res;
  }

  // handleCartClick(state);

  


  return (
    <div className='product-details'>
      <Navbar/>
      <div className="container">
        <div className="product-detail">
          <div className="product-image">
            <img src={state.item.image} alt="" />
          </div>
          <div className="product-info">
            <div className="product-title">
              <h3> {state.item.title} </h3>
            </div>
            <div className="desciption">
                {state.item.description}
            </div>
            <div className="rating">
              {state.item.rating.rate}
            </div>
            <div className="product-price">
              <h3>Rs. {toIndian(state.item.price*80)} </h3>
            </div>
            <div className="counter">
              <span>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-light" onClick={handleDecrement}>-</button>
              </span>
              <span>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-light">{count}</button>

              </span>
              <span>
              <button type="button" className="btn btn-light" onClick={handleIncrement}>+</button>
              </span>
              <div className="buying">
                <div className="buy">
                  <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Buy Now</button>
                </div>
                <div className="addtocart">
                  <button type="button" className="btn btn-primary btn-lg">Add to Cart</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </div>
  )
}

export default ProductDetails
```

I am getting null when multiple state is passed through the Link tag of router. It works fine when a single state is passed on.

[image: code when single is passed]

[image: This is the output when a single value is passed on]

[image: code when multiple data is passed]

[image: output for multiple data]

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @Arkellys I am new to stack overflow. But can u please review the code and see why am i getting null?

Comment: @AlokSingh https://reactrouter.com/en/main/components/link#state.
Can you try to pass the state like this?

Comment: @b3lg1c4 ya i did still facing the same issue. I am getting null when multiple states are passed. I works fine for the single state

Comment: @AlokSingh Ok, first, have you fixed in the `newTo` object of the first image the route pathname? You are passing the state to a route that does not exist.

Comment: @b3lg1c4 ya i did. I defined a new object const myData = { item: item,handleCartClick: handleCartClick} and Link as <Link to= 'product-details' state={myData}>

Comment: The data passed via route state needs to be JSON serializable. Javascript script functions are not serializable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try passing the data in one property like this:

```
<Link to='product-details' state={{data:myData}}>
```

Comment: Still same issue

Comment: @AlokSingh Ok, but i don't understand what do you mean that is not throwing null when you pass only one state...

Comment: It works completely fine when a single state is passed. but when multiple state were passed console shows error as "state is null"

Comment: Can you post the output when you pass one state, and when you pass two or more states?

Comment: When one state is passed like const myData = {item: item} then it works fine,but when passed like const myData = {item: item, handle: handle} then it throws error "state is null"

Comment: That's not make sense. You are saying that `<Link to='product-details' state={{item:item}}>`works, but `<Link to='product-details' state={{data:myData}}>` not working?

Comment: yes it's not working idk why.

Comment: Post the `console.log` output when you pass `{item:item}` and when you pass `{item:item,handler:handler}`

Comment: it's in the question description.

Comment: Mmm pretty weird. I don't really understand why adding one more prop to the object breaks the whole state

Comment: yea same. it's working fine for one state

Comment: @AlokSingh I just tested it out. It results that when you pass a function inside the state data of Link, it seems to break the entire state itself. If you try to pass an object with a string prop and a number prop, for example, it will work. It is maybe a bug...

Comment: @AlokSingh Here you  have the reason very well explained about your problem, i hope it helps: https://stackoverflow.com/a/74187887/14536183

Comment: thanks a lot bro for the help. I was stuck here for more than 4 hours.